# C# Filter Items In A List According To Multiple Criteria

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq, list

First, what my situation here is...

- My SomeObject has a property `string Status` which I am interested in for this scenario.
- Status property can contain "Open", "Closed", "Finished" values exactly.
- I have a method called `FilterObjects` which returns a `List<SomeObject>`
- Method accepts an argument same as its return type, `List<SomeObject>`
- Method is supposed to filter according to following cases explained below and return the list of objects.
- The `List<SomeObject>` I am sending as argument to my method is guaranteed to be in order (through their ID and type).

The cases are (all related to the `string Status` property I mentioned):

1. If any item in the list contains `Status = "Finished";` then eliminate all other elements that was in the original list and return only the object that has the "Finished" status.
2. If any item does **NOT** contain `Status = Finished` but contains "CLOSED", I need to check if there is any other item that has the value of "Open" after that "CLOSED" one. You can think of this as a "a task can be closed, but can be reopened. But once it is finished, it cannot be reopened".

   If it contains a "CLOSED" and does not have any "OPEN" after that item, I will ignore all the items before CLOSED and only return CLOSED object. If it contains "OPEN" after any closed, I need to return anything AFTER that CLOSED, by excluding itself.

I also tried explain the same thing with my awesome MS Paint skills.

[image]

The object itself is not really a problem, but my method is something like this:

```
private List<SomeObject> FilterObjects(List<SomeObject> objectList)
{
    var objects = objectList;
    var returnList = new List<SomeObject>();
                    
    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        if (obj.Status == "Finished")
        {
            returnList.Add(obj);
            return returnList;
        }
    }

    return new List<SomeObject>();
}
```

Long story short, what would be the best and most efficient way to apply all this logic in this single method? Honestly, I couldn't go further than the first case I already implemented, which is the FINISHED. Could this whole thing be done with some LINQ magic?

It is guaranteed that I receive an ordered list AND I will never get items more than a couple of hundred so the collection will never be massive.

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Tricky logic.  If I were you I'd write unit tests first, and stick to [really obvious code](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/09/01/no-comment-part-3.aspx).  Probably avoid LINQ.

Comment: and use an enum instead of those text strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
private List<SomeObject> FilterObjects(List<SomeObject> objectList)
{
    SomeObject finished = objectList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Status.Equals("Finished"));
    if (finished != null) { return new List<SomeObject> { finished }; }

    List<SomeObject> closed = objectList.SkipWhile(o => !o.Status.Equals("Closed")).ToList();
    if (closed.Count == 1) { return closed; }
    if (closed.Count > 1) { return closed.Skip(1).ToList(); }

    // if you need a new list object than return new List<SomeObject>(objectList);
    return objectList;
}
```

Comment: Small comment, but OP may have been ambiguous: He's specifically looking for an "Open" after a "Closed". Your test on whether the `closed` list contains one element is what I would have done, but it's possible that other statuses (that are not "Open") are present. I'd change the `.Count == 1` with `.Any(x => x.Status.Equals("Open"))`, which should be closer to what OP asked for (but may be functionally equivalent if it's impossible for any status other than "Open" to exist after a "Closed" status.

Comment: I would change finished check to  FirstOrDefault(), i think if there more than one finished item only one should be returned.  Nice solution, i did it with  Aggregate, but yours looks much  better compacter. +1

Comment: @Flater do you mean the `closed.Count > 1`?

Comment: No, the other check. `if (closed.Count == 1) { return closed; }` According to the original question, returning only the "Closed" element should happen **if there is no "Open" status after the "Closed" status**. It would be correcter to put `if (!closed.Any(x => x.Status.Equals("Open"))) { return closed.First(); }`. The difference is that if `closed` contains `{ "Closed", "Finished" }`, then it should return only the "Closed" element because there is no "Open" status following it (but there is still a different irrelevant status, therefore the `Count` is not equal to 1)

Comment: Footnote: it should return an List with a single object instead of just `closed.First()` but the comment length did not permit me to put that in.

Answer (score 3):

I really wouldn't bother using Linq for this, as you will either create an overly complicated instruction to manage or you will require several loop iterations. I would go for something like this instead:

```
    private List<SomeObject> FilterObjects(List<SomeObject> objectList)
    {
        int lastClosed = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < objectList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (objectList[i].Status == "Closed")
                lastClosed = i;
            else if (objectList[i].Status == "Finished")
                return new List<SomeObject>() { objectList[i] };
        }

        if (lastClosed > -1)
            if (lastClosed == objectList.Count - 1)
                return new List<SomeObject>() { objectList[lastClosed] };
            else 
                return objectList.Skip(lastClosed + 1).ToList();
        else
            return objectList;
    }
```

EDIT: slightly changed the last bit of code so that it won't trigger an exception if the objectList is empty

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is not well suited and inefficient for scenarios where you need to apply logic based on previous / next elements of a sequence.

The optimal way to apply your logic is to use a single loop and track the `Closed` status and the position where the status change occurred. At the end you'll return a single element at that position if the last status is `Closed`, or a range starting at that position otherwise.

```
static List<SomeObject> FilterObjects(List<SomeObject> objectList)
{
    int pos = 0;
    bool closed = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < objectList.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = objectList[i];

        if (item.Status == "Finished")
            return new List<SomeObject> { item };

        if (item.Status == (closed ? "Opened" : "Closed"))
        {
            pos = i;
            closed = !closed;
        }
    }
    return objectList.GetRange(pos, closed ? 1 : objectList.Count - pos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
public static IEnumerable<SomeObject> convert(this IEnumerable<SomeObject> input)
{
    var finished = input.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == "Finished");
    if (finished != null)
    {
        return new List<SomeObject> {finished};
    }
   return input.Aggregate(new List<SomeObject>(), (a, b) =>
   {
       if (!a.Any())
       {
          a.Add(b);
       }
       else if (b.Status == "Open")
       {
          if (a.Last().Status == "Closed")
          {
            a.Remove(a.Last());
          }
          a.Add(b);
       }
       else if (b.Status == "Closed")
       {
          a = new List<SomeObject> {b};
       }
       return a;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method like this. This is bare minimum you will have to add null check and exception handling.

```
public List<SomeCls> GetResult(List<SomeCls> lstData)
    {
        List<SomeCls> lstResult;

        if(lstData.Any(x=>x.Status=="Finished"))
        {
            lstResult = lstData.Where(x=>x.Status=="Finished").ToList();
        }

        else if(lstData.Any(x=>x.Status=="Closed"))
        {
            // Here assuming that there is only one Closed in whole list
            int index = lstData.FindIndex(0,lstData.Count(),x=>x.Status=="Closed");
            lstResult = lstData.GetRange(index,lstData.Count()-index);

            if(lstResult.Count()!=1) // check if it contains Open.
            {
                lstResult = lstResult.Where(x=>x.Status=="Open").ToList();
            }
        }
        else // Only Open
        {
            lstResult = lstData;
        }
        return lstResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
    private List<SomeObject> FilterObjects(List<SomeObject> objectList)
    {
        if (objectList.Where(x => x.Status == "Finished").Any())
        {
            return objectList.Where(x => x.Status == "Finished").ToList();
        }

        else if (objectList.Where(x => x.Status == "Closed").Any())
        {
            if (objectList.FindIndex(x => x.Status == "Closed") == objectList.Count() - 1)
            {
                return objectList.Where(x => x.Status == "Closed").ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return objectList.GetRange(objectList.FindIndex(x => x.Status == "Closed") + 1, objectList.Count() - (objectList.FindIndex(x => x.Status == "Closed") + 1));
            }
        }

        return objectList;
     }
```